# How to set the TimeoutManager on HttpListener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, httplistener

Starting from .NET framework 4.5 the [HttpListenertimeoutManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenertimeoutmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2#constructors) was introduced, which acts as a manager for HttpListeners:

> The timeout manager to use for an HttpListener object.

Which allows you to set different timeouts for the HttpListener using `TimeSpan` like so:

```
private HttpListenerTimeoutManager manager;

manager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
manager.HeaderWait = timespan.FromMinutes(2);
manager.DrainEntityBody= timespan.FromMinutes(2);
```

this seems like a neat thing to have to save a certain preset in, without having to set all the timeouts individually for any listener that may be running.

Now i want to set the `TimeoutManager` on my `HttpListener listener` to my newly created `manager`. However there seems to be **no** way to do that.

`listener.TimeoutManager = manager;` cannot be done as the property `listener.TimeoutManager` is *read only* (as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.timeoutmanager?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_HttpListener_TimeoutManager)).

But there is no alternative `listener.TimeoutManager.Set()` method to set it either, or any other setter method.

Creating a new HttpListener with the manager in its constructor `listener = new HttpListener(manager)` does not work either, as HttpListener has no constructor that takes 1 argument.

Meaning the only way i can edit the `HeaderWait` using the manager on my listener is to do the following:

`listener.TimeoutManager.HeaderWait = manager.HeaderWait;`

which really just comes down to doing

`listener.TimeoutManager.Headerwait = Timespan.FromMinutes(2);`

Which then seems the better option as it saves me from creating an additional variable, and it still forces me to set every timeout individually.

Am I misunderstanding the usecase of HttpListenerTimeoutManager, or overseeing the way of setting it here?

Using Unity with the .NET 4.x (which brings support up to .NET 4.7 class libraries) scripting runtime version.

Comment: have you try      HttpListenerTimeoutManager timeoutManager = listener.TimeoutManager; and after set the property of timeoutManager object ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either i'm afraid. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: has i can see in [this test](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.HttpListener/tests/HttpListenerTimeoutManagerTests.cs) class exemple, this seems that you have to call listener.TimeoutManager.Variable to set the data.

Comment: `this seems like a neat thing to have to save a certain preset in, without having to set all the timeouts individually for any listener that may be running.` I don't think that's the purpose of this class (actually, it's pretty obvious that it's not, otherwise it wouldn't be designed this way). I think it's only there to group all the types of timeouts in one place, to make the HttpListener simpler to use

Comment: Thanks for the example @Paul . You were indeed right, i made the error of doing it outside the class accidentally in my first attempt.

Comment: @KevinGosse I see. I suppose that does make sense looking at it like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting Paul and Kevin Gosse their comments into an answer for future reference:

as Kevin Gosse pointed out I was indeed wrong in thinking that a `HttpListenerTimeoutManager` can be used to manage the timeouts across multiple `HttpListener`s. Instead it is just there to

> group all the types of timeouts in one place, to make the HttpListener simpler to use

Which makes sense looking at the implementation of the `HttpListenerTimeoutManager` Class.

The correct way to use the `HttpListenerTimeoutManager` is by setting it to the property of `HttpListener.TimeoutManager` like so:

```
HttpListener listener;
HttpListenerTimeoutManager manager;

public Foo()
{
    manager = listener.TimeoutManager;
    manager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    manager.HeaderWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
}
```